# React module css Backdrop filter not working why?

Tags: css, reactjs, navbar, blur, backdrop

[image: Module.css code for nav]

what am i doing wrong here? why css is not applying on div and making it blur can someone help to make my navbar blur?

I want to make my navbar blurred

Comment: Try adding   `-webkit-filter: blur(28px);`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because you're adding blur to the container instead of the element in front of it. Check out this codesandbox where the `h1` has a blur applied to it: https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-microservice-gcvbm1?file=/src/App.js:87-96

When you remove the `container` class from the `div` you'll notice that the blur isn't visible.

**To be more clear: Backdrop-filter is applied to everything BEHIND the element that it's applied to.**